# Rails devise - Error al actualizar contraseña con redireccionamiento personalizado

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Actualmente me encuentro utilizando devise para realizar el cambio de contraseña de un usuario en mi sitio web con un redireccionamiento personalizado, como se muestra a continuación:

[image: Codigo con redireccionamiento personalizado]

Pero me encuentro con el inconveniente de que cuando se despliega la nueva vista, el cambio de contraseña se realizó sin tener en cuenta el redireccionamiento que se realizó en el if.

De tal manera que me gustaría saber que alternativas tengo para realizar dicha validación sin que se actualice dicho registro.

Quedo atento a sus preciados comentarios,

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil decir qué sucede sin ver los parámetros que estás recibiendo. Sin embargo el siguiente código funcionará en cualquier caso:

Comprueba que la antigua contraseña es correcta:

```
resource.valid_password(resource_params['password'])
```

Comprueba que la nueva contraseña no es la misma contraseña

```
resource.valid_password(resource_params['old_password'])
```